# How to create contracts on Ethereum block-chain in python?

Tags: python, storage, blockchain, ethereum

I want to create contract on Ethereum to store data. I'm beginner on this domain...Do we have a better solution ?

In this [post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7884/how-can-i-store-data-in-ethereum-blockchain?noredirect=1&lq=1), someone tell me to download a plugin. This is one way to do it, but I want to insert data in a block-chain with python (or other language).

I don't know where to start ... download Ethereum? Create an account?

Does it incur any cost? How much?

If contracts can be update, can I use Ethereum contract to prove work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't know where to start ... download Ethereum? Create an account?

1. Install the command line tools. [ethereum.org/cli](https://www.ethereum.org/cli)

   I would not recommend to start with the `pyethapp` (Python) or the `eth` (C++) client. Use `geth` (Golang) or `parity` (Rust). They are good to get started with and well documented.
2. Create a hello world contract. [ethereum.org/greeter](https://www.ethereum.org/greeter)

   `greeter` is the most simple smart contract deployed using the command line.

   ```
   contract mortal {
       /* Define variable owner of the type address*/
       address owner;

       /* this function is executed at initialization and sets the owner of the contract */
       function mortal() { owner = msg.sender; }

       /* Function to recover the funds on the contract */
       function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) selfdestruct(owner); }
   }

   contract greeter is mortal {
       /* define variable greeting of the type string */
       string greeting;

       /* this runs when the contract is executed */
       function greeter(string _greeting) public {
           greeting = _greeting;
       }

       /* main function */
       function greet() constant returns (string) {
           return greeting;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Come back here if you have *specific* issues with a client, with a contract source code or with deploying them on the blockchain.

Hope that helps getting you bootstrapped :)

Comment: Thank for your answer!!!! How many cost to insert contract in blockchain?

Comment: This contract is estimated to need 172 thousand gas to deploy. Gas preis is 20 Gwei. 20 Gwei * 172000 Gas = 0.00344 Ether which is around ~ 0.0379 USD at the time of writing.

Comment: Must I pay each time when I update or add data into the contract?

Comment: You can't update contracts, they're immutable. You can however have a proxy contract in front of the real contract(s), which simply calls to a contract adress that you have defined as a variable in the proxy contact.

Comment: @baloo, tank for your answer! Do you know if I need to create an account after I downloaded ethereum command line before create contract? What is the diferents between connection to the private testnet and the public network?

Answer (score 0):

You may also use [(py)ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum) and [serpent](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Serpent) *- in order to keep the python spirit -* If it is ok for you, you may take a look at "[A Programmer’s Guide to Ethereum and Serpent](https://mc2-umd.github.io/ethereumlab/docs/serpent_tutorial.pdf)".
Regards